# Is it a good option to setup the backup application in the remote computer?

Tags: backup

I have a main computer and I would like to make backups of a folder that will be stored in a remote computer.

So I have the option to install the application in the main computer, share a folder in the remote computer and store the backup there.

But I was thinking that I could install the backup application in the remote computer, so perhaps I could avoid to install applications in the main computer and save resources.

But I am not sure if this is a good practice or not, because most of the backup applications has the option to store a copy en a network device, so I guess the common way it is install the application in the computer that will be backupped, but I would like to know if there is another options.

Thanks.

Comment: When possible, backups should always be done of the computer/server housing the information, as doing remote backups is inefficient since doing so over WAN is restricted to the ISP upload throughput of the remote machine and the download throughput of the local machine _(it will always be faster to backup to locally connected storage - e.g. remote machine backs up to it's locally connected storage)_. If the remote machine supports SSH, backups can be initiated remotely _(if BSD/Linux,`tmux` would be recommended to use, else closing the SSH connection stops all terminal operations)_

Answer (score 0):

It depends how application works.

For example: backuppc pings the host that needs to be backup, and when host is up and schedule to do backup is due, then it starts a backup.

Now depending on how your pc's work it can vary.

If the second pc where you store backup is up all time then is best to set up the pc you want to backup to send the files to that pc (second pc becaomse basically a share, network drive) there are many apps that can do this very well including windows via windows backup.

My advice do a docker container with backuppc or install backuppc on second computer (were the backups will live) and set up backuppc to get the files from your pc like i explained up. The advantage of this is that is proven to work very reiable and  you have history and incremental backups.

Comment: In my case the second computer will be connected all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool to create program-and-system INDEPENDENT backups.

Linux has a suite of these from `dd` to `rsync` and `tar`

None of these will consume excess resources, and can always be (`cron`) scheduled for low use times (ie, overnight) or priority-lowered with `nice`

These can be piped over a network without excessively hogging resources too, or work on portable hard drives, etc, etc.

"Good practice" depends on your end use. How much downtime is acceptable, how much availability is required, how often the backup needs to be accessed, tested, restored etc. For general home use on mechanical hard disks for important data, I go by the old 3-2-1: 3 copies (one is the system you use daily), 2 different media, 1 offsite.